# Heroku node + react app: anchor tag auth request unhandled

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I'm building a node + express server, with create-react-app to the frontend.
I used passportjs for auth routes handling, and all the stuff totally working on localhost ( backend on port 5000 and frontend on port 3000, with a proxy ).
When I deploy to Heroku, seems like the server can't recognize my auth routes and so heroku serve up static index.html.
If I test my APIs with Postman all seems to work ( I can see the html page for google oauth ), but with an anchor tag in my react app or manually writing the endpoint in the url, I can see only the same page reloading.

My server index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const passport = require('passport')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const path = require('path')

// KEYS
const keys = require('./config/keys')

// MONGOOSE MODELS
require('./models/User')

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI)

// PASSPORT SETUP
require('./config/passport')

// CREATE THE SERVER
const app = express()

// EXTERNAL MIDDLEWARES
require('./middlewares/external')(app)

// ROUTE HANDLERS
require('./routes/authRoutes')(app)

// PRODUCTION SETUP
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // express serve up production assets ( main.js, main.css )
  app.use(express.static('client/build'))
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  })
}

// START THE SERVER
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(PORT)
```

Flow:

LOCALHOST:
react app starts -> I click 'Google Login' -> GET request to "/auth/google" -> google oauth flow -> redirect to "/" and my react app reappears, the user is logged in.

HEROKU:
react app on my-app.herokuapp.com/ -> click on "Google Login" -> the page reloads, nothing happens. the user is not logged in.

Please guys, help me.
Thanks

Comment: When you do heroku logs --tail, do you see any errors coming from heroku?

Comment: no errors, anything seems to work

Comment: I think with Oauth there is an "authorized url to redirect to" list in their dashboard. Do you have a redirect to url listed in there? I think thats what they use to redirect back to your app

Comment: I thought it too, but if I test my "/auth/google" api endpoint with Postman I can see the google login html page. If there was an "authorized url to redirect to" google would tell me after login, with a proper error page.

Comment: @DarioIelardi Seems like you followed the tutorial from Stephen Grider, because I'm having the same issue. Did you somehow fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of the service worker being installed by default to make your app a [Progressive Web App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2398)

To determine if this is an issue for you, test your heroku production mode app in incognito mode.  The request for /auth/google should now reach the server and behave as it does in development.

Once you determine it is an issue, you can remove the

```
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
```

from your /client/src/index.js file.

You browser cache may already contain an installed service worker so you may have to

1. clear browser cache on a user browsers
2. uninstall the server worker programmatically

   ```
   import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';
   ....
   unregister();
   ```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It solved a bug that I was trying to fix from the past week.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with same symptoms exactly.

For me the cause was a typo in the keys: in `server/config/prod.js` I had a line reading `cookieKey: process.env.COOKIE_KEY` but in Heroku Config Variables that variable was named `cookieKey`. Renaming it to `COOKIE_KEY` inside Heroku solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed the Stephen Grider tutorial one thing I'm wondering: Is your passport.js file in config or services? I see you've written in index.js: `require('./config/passport')`
whereas mine in index.js is `require('./services/passport')`

may not be your solution to the google oauth flow hanging in production but may help.